# Why isn't Task.Delay working in an Azure Function App?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a C# function app (.net Core 3.1) that processes items from a queue.  I need to slow down the processing as there is another external API that I need to talk to and it is rate limited.

I am using

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

to pause the function app for a period of time between calls to the API.  In my local development environment it works perfectly and pauses for the time period given.  When deployed to Azure it would appear that the delay is not occurring and processing of the queue items proceeds much quicker than expected.

I have tried this with a long period of 10000ms (10 seconds) and can see the delay when testing locally but when deployed to Azure the queue items are used up reasonably quickly and certainly less 10 seconds apart.

The function declaration looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("ProcessUserQueue")]
public async Task RunAsync([QueueTrigger(QueueNames.ProcessUserQueueName)]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"ProcessUserQueue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    await _userService.ProcessUserAsync(myQueueItem, log);
}
```

Inside of ProcessUserAsync the first thing I do is call

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

and it works, but only in local dev environment.

My host.json looks like this (with a queue batch size of one):

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is not working, or how to better limit the speed of API calls within the function?

Comment: Upon arriving of a message a new function instance can run `RunAsync`. Those instances are not aware of each other.

Comment: Using `Task.Delay` to rate-limit requests to an API is much like using a spoon to attempt to save the *Titanic*.

Comment: Peter, I think you are onto it.  I used one of the related posts and discovered an app setting of WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT = 1 which should limit the  app to one instance.  This seemed to help a bit but not completely. Then I also modifed the host.json to include "newBatchThreshold": 0.  The function app seems to be behaving itself now.  Will need to do some more testing yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to delay the process:

1. Instead of using `Task.Delay()` you can use `Thread.Sleep()`.

   **Task.Delay(**) is used for a logical delay without blocking the current thread.

   **Thread.Sleep()** is used for blocking the current thread.
2. You can use `durable functions` to achieve the process delay [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp)
3. it consists of setting an `initialVisibilityDelay` : [Add message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

> For initialVisibilityDelay you need to add a temporary queue and then add a function.

Refer for more [info](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0bcd83dd-3f90-4252-8a46-bce56b6d4284/azure-function-set-trigger-delay?forum=AzureFunctions)

Comment: Can confirm that replacing Task.Delay() with Thread.Sleep() worked for me. Task.Delay() worked when testing locally but not when deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding delay to the HttpTrigger function while reading the Queue is not going to work in a real-world scenario as the function will timeout if the processing of the items took longer than the function timeout period.

For operations that can take longer than the HttpTrigger function timeout time, use **Azure Durable Functions**.

Durable Functions provides durable **timers** for use in orchestrator functions to implement delays or to set up timeouts on async actions.

```
[FunctionName("BillingIssuer")]
public static async Task Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        DateTime deadline = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
        await context.CreateTimer(deadline, CancellationToken.None);
        await context.CallActivityAsync("SendBillingEvent");
    }
}
```

For implementing delays in Azure Durable function using Timers, see article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp

For Azure Durable functions see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp